# Como retirar uma parte especifica de uma string

Tags: php

Vamos dizer que eu tenho um arquivo chamado `Icon.png` e eu vou zipar ele, vai ficar `Icon.png.zip` mas eu quero que se chame apenas `Icon.zip`, como faço para retirar a parte `.png` do nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você usa o PHP 5.2.0 para cima, pode usar a função `pathinfo` com a constante `PATHINFO_FILENAME`, isso irá lhe retornar apenas o nome do arquivo. Sendo assim, é só concatenar o `.zip`:

```
<?php
  $nome_arquivo = "Icon.png";
  $novo_nome =  pathinfo($nome_arquivo, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.zip';
  echo $novo_nome; // Retorna "Icon.zip"
?>
```

Ideone: https://ideone.com/14vP36

---

Para versões abaixo, é preciso usar a constante `PATHINFO_BASENAME`, porém esta irá nos retornar todo o nome do arquivo (usando o primeiro código como exemplo, `Icon.png`). O que você pode fazer é usar o `preg_replace` para obter o nome do arquivo e depois concatenar o `.zip`. Exemplo:

```
<?php
  $nome_arquivo = "Icon.png";
  $arquivo = pathinfo($nome_arquivo, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
  $novo_nome = preg_replace('/(.+?)\.[^.]*$|$/', '$1', $nome_arquivo) . '.zip';
  echo $novo_nome; // Retorna "Icon.zip"
?>
```

Ideone: https://ideone.com/5F04Jr

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda mano

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), veja um exemplo funcional [aqui](http://codepad.org/E4a6YL7L).

```
<?php
    $valor = "Icon.png.zip";
    $valor = str_replace(".png", "", $valor);
    echo $valor;
?>
```

Você também pode passar um array contendo as palavras que você quer substituir:

```
<?php
    // array com os valores que devem ser substuidos
    $ext = array(".png", ".jpg", ".gif");

    $png = "IconPNG.png.zip";
    $png = str_replace($ext, "", $png);

    $jpg = str_replace($ext, "", "IconJPG.jpg.zip");

    echo $png . "\n";
    echo $jpg;
?>
```

Exemplo funcional [aqui](http://codepad.org/Qdlbz1dG).

Comment: Vlw pela sua ajuda. porem eu não vou saber qual a extensão do arquivo para usar o replace :c

Comment: Entendi! Tudo bem. :)